# Python formatting % where int is from the set

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have such line:

```
if something in ["name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5"]
```

and I wonder if I can write it shorter using formatting. I know that I can write it like that:

```
if something in ["name_%d" %(1), "name_%d" %(2), "name_%d" %(3)]:
```

but because those strings have the same part "name_" I hoped that there is maybe shorter way of formatting, similar to this one (this doesn't work):

```
if something in ["name_%d" %(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see the benefit of trying to do this. How large might the list of names be? If it is only five, don't obfuscate it, if it is longer just create the list before the `if` with a comprehension and then use it.

Comment: Also, an `f`-string solution with Python 3.6 is another alternative `{f'name_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your list with a list comprehension easily:

```
if something in ['name_%d' % i for i in range(1, 6)]:
```

*However*, you are really just looking for a text pattern; a regular expression can test that for you more efficiently:

```
import re

if re.match(r'name_[1-6]$', something):
```

or you could just test if the string starts with a name:

```
if something.startswith('name_') and something[5:] in {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}:
```

In Python 3, using a *static* set literal to test for membership against is going to be faster than using a list. Both are cached in the bytecode as immutable structures, but testing against a set takes O(1) constant time, vs. O(N) time for a list. However, if you are *generating* the set or list, you still pay a O(N) cost just to build that object. Generating a list object is faster (no hashing required), which makes it ever so slightly faster to test against. A generator expression is slower still.

Timing comparisons for the comprehension approaches (generator expression, set and list comprehensions, for first, last and miss cases):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)): pass',
...               'something="name1"')
2.0784148779930547
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)}: pass',
...               'something="name1"')
2.032067227992229
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)]: pass',
...               'something="name1"')
1.9060910780681297
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)): pass',
...               'something="name5"')
2.1426312710391358
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)}: pass',
...               'something="name5"')
2.0627736690221354
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)]: pass',
...               'something="name5"')
1.9719348540529609
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)): pass',
...               'something="name42"')
2.160375243984163
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)}: pass',
...               'something="name42"')
2.0166494220029563
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)]: pass',
...               'something="name42"')
2.0706132350023836
```

For just 5 items, it's a bit of a wash, with perhaps the list comprehension winning.

For more 1000 possible names:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)): pass',
...               'something="name1"', number=10**4)
3.895413015037775
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)}: pass',
...               'something="name1"', number=10**4)
3.459794587106444
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)]: pass',
...               'something="name1"', number=10**4)
3.510508105973713
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)): pass',
...               'something="name1000"', number=10**4)
3.792039962951094
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)}: pass',
...               'something="name1000"', number=10**4)
3.859958241926506
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)]: pass',
...               'something="name1000"', number=10**4)
3.561700245947577
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)): pass',
...               'something="name1009"', number=10**4)
3.616139759076759
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in {"name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)}: pass',
...               'something="name1009"', number=10**4)
3.4787185511086136
>>> timeit.timeit('if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 1001)]: pass',
...               'something="name1009"', number=10**4)
3.2148393219104037
```

The list comprehension still has the edge, by a small margin.

However, using a regular expression is *easily* faster than that, by a factor of 3:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('if re.match(r"name_[1-5]$", something): pass',
...               'import re; something="name1"')
0.7225337530253455
>>> timeit.timeit('if re.match(r"name_[1-5]$", something): pass',
...               'import re; something="name5"')
0.7184386339504272
>>> timeit.timeit('if re.match(r"name_[1-5]$", something): pass',
...               'import re; something="name42"')
0.7749457659665495
```

This can be made faster still by caching the `re.compile(..)` result.

The clear winner is simple text matching:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('if something.startswith("name_") and something[5:] in {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}: pass',
...               'something="name1"')
0.15361014590598643
>>> timeit.timeit('if something.startswith("name_") and something[5:] in {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}: pass',
...               'something="name5"')
0.14619109802879393
>>> timeit.timeit('if something.startswith("name_") and something[5:] in {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}: pass',
...               'something="name42"')
0.1544568829704076
```

This is about 15 times faster than the fastest list comprehension test.

Comment: Both `set`s and `list`s are mutable. Use generators if you want to swap the `list` for something, which would give you better build complexity.

Comment: @Adirio: The Python compiler *optimises* this case. When you use a list or set with only immutable values, a tuple or frozenset is used instead.

Comment: @Adirio: I'll need to time this, but for smaller lists I strongly suspect that the list or set comprehension is going to be faster in most cases; even for the most optimistic case perhaps. That's because a generator expression has a higher setup cost.

Comment: @Adirio: timings added. Testing with startswith blows generator expressions out of the water, and list comprehensions are only marginally faster than a generator expression.

Comment: Well, that is relying on interpret optimizations.

Comment: @Adirio: Almost nothing in the timings is peephole optimised. There are no static sets or lists, except for the `something[5:] in {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}` part.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if something in ["name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)]:
```

It uses list comprehension, the `range(start, end)` function (which includes the start but not the end) and `str.format()`, all quite pythonic.

Range by default starts at 0 so you could also go for:

```
if something in ["name_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(5)]:
```

I would also suggest swaping the list for a generator expresion:

```
if something in ("name_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 6)):

if something in ("name_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(5)):
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
if something in ['name_'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: No `xrange` in Python3